# How to derived solution by Big'O Notation with Algorithm Efficiency?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was been given with this algorithm and I was told to provide its efficiency in Big'O Notation and explained the derivation. 
I have tried to research about Big'O Notation and algorithm efficiency but still I am not able to solve the following question. These are the algorithms given:

```
i= 100

loop( i > 10)

    num = 1;

    loop( num < = 1000)

         num = i*num

    end loop

    i= i /2;

end loop
```

I hope anyone could help me with this question, this is an exercise not homework.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the input here ? This code doesn't actually change regarding to anything and in the way it is, It's of O(1). At most doing several hundreds of operations (As @Yola suggested O(lg(i)) * O(log(num base i)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if initial value of i - N, here 100, and max allowed value of num - M is the input, then the answer is `log(N)*log(M)`.

So, outer loops will be executed `log(N, 2)` times. And inner loop will be executed `log(M, current_value_of_i)` times.

EDIT: to answer SilverArcher's comment.
During one iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop can't be executed more than `log(1000,11)` times.

Comment: From what I have learnt, i think this is linear logarithmic loops, the formula is O(nlog2n). But I am not sure with this question... Realli confusing now.

Comment: @SilverArcher what is your n?

Comment: @Yola He is asking _us_ this question, I believe.

Comment: can we assumed that n is 10 ?

Comment: @Silver Archer well, we can assume it, but a formula must work with `n -> infinity`.

Comment: I see, okay thanks ! I will research more on this topic and try to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this code always does exactly the same thing every time - there's no inputs you can change to cause it to run for a longer or shorter amount of time. As a result, the time complexity is O(1), since the runtime is independent of the size of the input.

Comment: I think he wants `i` to be the variable for which the running time should be described.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's hard to tell from the question - the explicit assignment of 100 to `i` makes me a bit skeptical about that. I figure that either (1) the exercise is designed to show what O(1) means, in which case this answe is right, or (2) it's a typo in the question or a poorly-designed question, in which case the other answer would be on the right track.

Comment: For values of `i` greater than 1000, the complexity appears to be `O(lg_2 i)`, since the inner loop would basically no-op.  The complexity for values of `i` less than 1000 is not clear to me.

Comment: With `i` unambiguously given a fixed value there's a part of me that suspects that this code is supposed to demonstrate O(1) complexity (this is the sort of thing I might sneakily give my students). That inner loop always runs O(1) times, so yes, the complexity would be O(log n) (dropping the log base because big-O eats constant log bases.)